# mod_rewrite .htaccess remove part of url prestashop blog

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop-1.6

I have a blog module in my prestashop site. Here's an example URL of a post: mydomain/blog/aprender-idiomas-online/polonia-oportunidades-de-negocio

I would like to change this URL to something simpler, like mydomain/polonia-oportunidades-de-negocio
basically removing this part **/blog/aprender-idiomas-online** from the URL

I've tried a million things but I can't get it to work. I think it should be adding something like this in the .htaccess but it doesn't do anything..

```
    RewriteRule ^/blog/aprender-idiomas-online/(.*)$ /$1
```

That's my .htaccess, as you can see it already has some rewrite rules but I'm too newbie to understand them fully. I've put my rule right after *RewriteEngine on*

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/blog/aprender-idiomas-online/(.*)$ /$1
    RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
    RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    # Images
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %       {ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
    RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
    # AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
    RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

    # Dispatcher
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/aprender-idiomas-online/(.*)$ /$1
```

would take

```
http://example.com/blog/apprender/idiomas-online/foo/bar/baz
```

and turn it into

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz
```

which is probably NOT going to exist on your server, leading to a 404 error.

It should be rewriting to an actual script or file, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/aprender-idiomas-online/(.*)$ /controller.php?path=$1
```

which would produce

```
http://example.com/controller.php?path=foo/bar/baz
```